# Run function only on specific pages

Tags: javascript

I want an IIFE to run only on specific pages like so

```js
(function(){
  if (!window.location.pathname.includes("index.html")) return
  // ... other code to execute if the page is index.html
})()
```

The above code works like a charm. The problem is, whenever I insert multiple conditions the IIFE never runs regardless of the current HTML page in the browser, for example

```js
if (!window.location.pathname.includes("index.html") || !window.location.pathname.includes("other.html")) return
```

The issue is relevant when I want to ensure that a function only runs on index.html or "/" if the HTML page is omitted from the URI - or if I want the IIFE to run only on a set of specific pages as the example above.

Comment: You should use ```&&``` instead of ```||```, so this is how it looks like ```if (!window.location.pathname.includes("index.html") && !window.location.pathname.includes("other.html")) return```

Comment: I am dumb... Thank you @KeyboardCorporation

Answer (score 0):

you need to trace your code carefully, the solution of this problem to replace only one logical operator replace **||** with **&&** :

inside IIFE :

```
if (!window.location.pathname.includes("index.html") && !window.location.pathname.includes("other.html")) return
```

or *I Suggest for you* to try any way to merge the two part for condition to only one part for Example ***by using RegEx*** :

```
  if (! /\b(index|other)\b/.test(window.location.pathname)) return;
```